# python 2.7 chained conditions If Else not working. What's wrong?

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement, conditional-statements

I can't figure out why the following doesn't work.

```
# Example
print "So, yes or no?"
answer = raw_input()
print answer
if answer == "Yes":
        print "Yes indeed!"
elif answer == "yes" or "y":
        print "Oh yeah!"
elif answer == "No":
        print "No it isn't!"
elif answer == "no" or "n":
        print "Not really!"
else: 
        print "Say what?"
```

When I remove the *or*, it does work. What am I doing wrong?

-edit-
I have it now, thanks a lot!

```
# Example
print "So, yes or no?"
answer = raw_input()
print answer
if answer in "Yes":
        print "Yes indeed!"
elif answer in ("yes", "y"):
        print "Oh yeah!"
elif answer in "No":
        print "No it isn't!"
elif answer in ("no", "n"):
        print "Not really!"
else: 
    print "Say what?"
```

Comment: define what *works* and *doesn't work* mean in your case.

Comment: What I _want_ is that when raw_input is yes or y, it prints Oh yeah! right now, every print output is Yes indeed! No matter if the input given at raw_input is  n, no or No.

Comment: then replace `answer == "yes" or "y"` with `answer in ["yes", "y"]` or what Padraic suggested in his answer

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I test one variable against multiple values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-do-i-test-one-variable-against-multiple-values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
elif answer == "yes" or  answer == "y":
elif answer == "No" or answer == "n":
```

Using `elif answer == "yes" or  "y":` etc.. you are basically checking `if bool("n")` not comparing if `answer` is equal to  `"n"` so your statements will always evaluate to True:

any non empty string will always evaluate to True:

```
In [38]: bool("n")
Out[38]: True
In [39]: bool("y")
Out[39]: True  
In [40]: bool("")
Out[40]: False
```

You can also test for membership using in if you want to check against more than one value:

```
 elif answer in {"yes", "y"}:
```

Comment: Just started to teach myself python as first programming language so it still is gibberish to me. I don't understand the boolean stuff yet, but your answer worked as well indeed! Might have missed something at the first attempt - as expected. This time gives me the output I was looking for!

Comment: @Patrick.no worries.  I suggest you check this out http://anandology.com/python-practice-book/index.html

Answer (score 3):

One problem I see is this:

```
elif answer == "yes" or "y":
```

that literally translates to "if answer is yes or True" which always result in True.

You could write it like this:

```
elif answer in ("yes", "y"):
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
answer == "Yes" or "y"
```

to:

```
answer == "Yes" or answer == "y"
```

or even:

```
answer in ("Yes", "y")
```

Comment: bottom one did it - thanks! `answer in ("Yes", "y")`